# Eclipse Git Team Provider installation issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse, git

Got Eclipse 3.8.1 (as this is what is available in the Ubuntu repo) installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS however when installing Eclipse Git Team Provider, I get following issue

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
  Missing requirement: Git Team Provider UI 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.ui 3.4.1.201406201815-r) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Git Team Provider 3.4.1.201406201815-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 3.4.1.201406201815-r)
    To: org.eclipse.egit.ui [3.4.1.201406201815-r]
```

Any help highly appreciated

Comment: I'd suggest installing Eclipse by downloading the tarball from the website and extracting. 3.8 is a very old version

Answer (score 3):

This is occuring due to mismatch in Eclipse version targeted by EGit

To avoid this do the following

1. Check Your Eclipse version
2. Then see the EGit version corresponding to your Eclipse Version at [What versions of Eclipse does EGit target](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#What_versions_of_Eclipse_does_EGit_target.3F)
3. Then find the corresponding EGit packages in the archives [Archives](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F) and use it in the Install New Softwares section